# How to save log info to a file with nosetests and logging package

Tags: logging, nose

I'm creating a custom logging module to implement in an application framework. And I'm using PyCharm with the `unittest` module and nosetests as my test runner.

Here is a simple tests case, but it doesn't save the output to the file `/tmp/test.log` as I'd hoped.

```
import unittest
import logging

class Logger_class____test_cases(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_log_file_basics(self):
        # set up logging to file - see previous section for more details
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                            filename='/tmp/test.log')
        # define a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
        console = logging.StreamHandler()
        console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        # set a format which is simpler for console use
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
        # tell the handler to use this format
        console.setFormatter(formatter)
        # add the handler to the root logger
        logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

        # Now, we can log to the root logger, or any other logger. First the root...
        logging.info('Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.')

        # Now, define a couple of other loggers which might represent areas in your
        # application:
        logger1 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area1')
        logger2 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area2')

        logger1.debug('Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim.')
        logger1.info('How quickly daft jumping zebras vex.')
        logger2.warning('Jail zesty vixen who grabbed pay from quack.')
        logger2.error('The five boxing wizards jump quickly.')
```

How do I get nosetests to write the log output to a file?  It seems like it has something to do with nosetests capturing `stdout` and `stderr`, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I got the code from the [Python logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had a default log file name configured in a global module in my framework.

I had something like the following which was overriding my test case:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                        filename='log_file_name.log',
                        filemode='w')
```

And of course Murphy's law, if I post a question, I will shortly find the answer.  lol